# mysql find only unique records in a subquery and show the count

Tags: mysql, subquery

i have two tables i am trying to get information from.

login table - which has the list of employees

projects table - which has the projects

in short, i am trying to write a query that will select the copywriters and perform a subquery on each that will return a field dubbed 'open_projects'. This, i can get to work with the below sql:

```
select web_login_id,
                (select count(project_web_id) from project
                where copywriter = web_login_id
                and (`status` = 'open' or `status` = 'qual')) as open_projects from login
                where roles like '%copywriter%'
                and tierLevel like '%c1%'
                order by open_projects asc
```

This returns something like:

1982983     3

1982690     22

2987398     5

The problem with this is that sometimes 5 or 6 of the projects will belong to the same client and are not actually being worked on as they are dealt with in a queue-ish fashion.

My question is how to modify the above sql so that the subquery will GROUP subset based on the client_login_id field.

This sql gives me an error of : subquery returns more than 1 row

```
select web_login_id,
                (select count(project_web_id) from project
                where copywriter = web_login_id
                and (`status` = 'open' or `status` = 'qual') group by client_login_id) as open_projects from login
                where roles like '%copywriter%'
                and tierLevel like '%c1%'
                order by open_projects asc
```

Comment: that's because your subquery:

    select count(project_web_id) from project
                    where copywriter = web_login_id
                    and (`status` = 'open' or `status` = 'qual') group by client_login_id

it's returning more that one result,

Comment: yes i'm aware of that. but i don't know how to modify it so it just give me a grouped count of open projects based on the client_login_id

Comment: i need sql to return a employee_id and no_of_open_projects where the subquery counts the number of unique client_ids in projects that have employee_id, telling me how many clients each employee has

Comment: It would help if you gave a sample of inputs and outputs to better see what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rephrase this as an explicit join.  I think the following does the trick:

```
select web_login_id, cw.open_projects
from login l left outer join
      (select copywriter, count(project_web_id) as open_projects
       from project
       where `status`  in ('open', 'qual')
       group by copywriter
      ) cw
      on l.web_login_id = cw.copywriter
where l.roles like '%copywriter%' and l.tierLevel like '%c1%' 
order by open_projects asc
```

I'm not sure what the "group by client_login_id" is doing.  It doesn't seem necessary.

Once you've done this, you can return as many columns as you like from the subquery.

Comment: this doesn't work. it gives me the exact same result as my query above. i will try more things.

Comment: This returns an error about a subquery returning more than one row?

Comment: i mean it returns the same as my original query that i posted

Comment: Is it possible that you want count(distinct client_login_id) staed of count(project_web_id)?